Series Sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i 2^{-(i-1)} $
Please see following information :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i f_i=1\cdot 1+2\cdot 2^{-1}+3\cdot 2^{-2}+4\cdot 2^{-3}+5\cdot 2^{-4}+\cdots+n\cdot 2^{-(n-1)}\tag{1}$$
Multiply Eq.(1) by 2, we get
$$2\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i f_i= 2(1\cdot 1+2\cdot 2^{-1}+3\cdot 2^{-2}+4\cdot 2^{-3}+5\cdot 2^{-4}+\cdots+n\cdot 2^{-(n-1)})\tag{2}$$
Subtracting Eq.(1) from Eq.(2), We get
$$2+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+\cdots+2^{-(n-1)}\tag{3}$$
My problem is that I couldn't get Eq.(3) when I subtract Eq.(1) from Eq.(2)
Please help me.
Humble Request 
Someone suggested that this question is duplicate but it is different. This question is not duplicate. I wants to answer this question because it helps some viewers. So please reopen this question.

That's because you don't get eq. 3 subtracting eq. 1 from eq. 2. That's plain wrong.

What happens if you move the factor of 2 into the exponents of all the terms of eq. (2)?

Note that that doesn't exactly give you what you want, the $2^{-(n-1)}$ term isn't quite right, but otherwise it's pretty close

$$2\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i f_i= (2+2^{2}\cdot 2^{-1}+3\cdot 2^{-1}+4\cdot 2^{-2}+5\cdot 2^{-3}+\cdots+n\cdot 2^{-(n-2)})\tag{2}$$

How to get a result in termwise difference?

The second term of $(2)$ after distribution of the multiplication should be $2\cdot 2^{1-1}$ to give the most obvious form.  Then the final result of the subtraction would have leading constant $3$...

What is $x_i,f_i?$

$x_i = 1,2,3,...,n$ and $f_i = 1,2^{-1},2^{-2},2^{-3},...,2^{-(n-1)}$

Why did someone put a -1 point to my answer? I guess the result is true.

So, the action linking this question as a duplicate is correct as far as showing a reliable method for solving it.  The method you were attempting to use is a discrete form of the same method: instead of differentiation you were using finite differences.  The underlying mechanism that demonstrates the result is the same.

Let us call this sum by $S_n$. Then the su. can be rearranged as
$$S_n=1+2^{-1}(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{-i}+S_{n}-n2^{-(n-1)}) $$
$$\frac{S_n}{2}=1+(1-2^{-(n-1)})-n2^{-n}=2-2^{-(n-1)}-n2^{-n}$$
$$S_n=4-2^{-(n-2)}-n2^{-(n-1)}=4-(n+2)\cdot 2^{-(n-1)}$$
Note also that the sum of the series is
$$ S:=\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\cdot 2^{-(i-1)}=4.$$

Your first equation is excessively confusing and probably prompted a down vote (not from me).
